# Create custom DynamoDB format for my sealed Trait

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb

I am totally new to DynamoDB and trying to insert some data into it.
I have a case class like this

```
case class JobInfo(
                    jobId: String,
                    status: JobStatus,
                    name: String,
                    scheduledTime: DateTime,
                    startTime: Option[DateTime] = None,
                    endTime: Option[DateTime] = None,
                    organisationId: Option[String] = None
                  )
```

and i have defined the implicit for this class like this

```
implicit val formatFarm: DynamoFormat[JobInfo] = deriveDynamoFormat[JobInfo]
```

one of the field in this case class is jJobStatus, which is defined as

```
sealed trait JobStatus {
  def status: String
}

object JobStatus {
  case object Waiting extends JobStatus { val status = "waiting" }
  case object Running extends JobStatus { val status = "running" }
  case object Success extends JobStatus { val status = "success" }
  case object Failure extends JobStatus { val status = "failure" }
}
```

for inserting the data into Mongo I had written the implicit codec but I am not sure how to write it for dynamo for Job Status
i tried `implicit val dynamocodec = deriveDynamoFormat[JobStatus]`
but when I inserted  data into DynamoDB for the table

```
val table = Table[JobInfo]("testJob")
```

like given below:

```
table.put(JobInfo("2", Waiting , "job2", DateTime.parse("2016-11-07T15:29:20.348+0000"),None, None, Some("orgid2")))
```

, the Status column was added like

```
{ "Waiting" : { "S" : "Waiting" } } in dynamo table
```

it should have been the lower case one "waiting".
I think the dynamoformat for JobStatus has to be something else, If someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after going through the library myself. COuldn't find this answer on internet, so thought of posting myself

```
sealed trait JobStatus1 {
  def status: String
}

        object JobStatus1 {
      case object Waiting1 extends JobStatus1 { val status = "waiting" }
      case object Running1 extends JobStatus1 { val status = "running" }
      case object Success1 extends JobStatus1 { val status = "success" }
      case object Failure1 extends JobStatus1 { val status = "failure" }
    
      def getJobStatusFromString(name: String): Either[DynamoReadError, JobStatus1] = name match {
        case Waiting1.status => Right(Waiting1)
        case Running1.status => Right(Running1)
        case Success1.status => Right(Success1)
        case Failure1.status => Right(Failure1)
        case _ => Left(TypeCoercionError(new Exception(" invalid value")))
    
      }

    implicit val jobStatusFormat = DynamoFormat.xmap[JobStatus1, String]( JobStatus1.getJobStatusFromString(_) ,_.status)
}
```